# DocumentListener limits characters - affects copy/paste

Tags: java, filter, documentlistener

I have DocumentLitener that converts all text to uppercase and it also limits the amount of text that can be entered. Here is my class:

public class UppercaseDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {

```
private int limit;

public UppercaseDocumentFilter(int maxCharacters) {
    limit = maxCharacters;
}

@Override
public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, String text, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
    if (fb.getDocument().getLength() + text.length() > limit) {
        return;
    }
    fb.insertString(offset, text.toUpperCase(), attr);

}

@Override
public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
    if (fb.getDocument().getLength() + text.length() > limit) {
        return;
    }
    fb.replace(offset, length, text.toUpperCase(), attrs);
}

@Override
public void remove(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length) throws BadLocationException {
    fb.remove(offset, length);
}
```

}

My problem is this. Let's say that textfield has a character limit of 10. I enter 5 characters. Then I copy a 6 character word. I CTRL+A (select all) text in the field and try to paste the 6 character word, replacing the 5 character one. However, it won't let me do it and I can only assume its due to DocumentListener thinking I am doing 5+6 which is more than the 10 char limit.

Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0):

> if (fb.getDocument().getLength() + text.length() > limit)

Your calculation doesn't take into account the number of characters that will be removed, as specified by the `length` parameter of the replace(...) method.

Take a look at the [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) example from the Swing tutorial for a solution.